# Looking for a way to get a detailed description of ZTERM

Tags: abap

I am currently trying to program a function module which should, in theory, output a custom table like `T052`, but with an additional field `Z_TEXTLONG`, which explains the details of the chosen `ZTERM`, akin to the text in `FI_F4_ZTERM`'s popup. Here's what I tried:

```
LOOP AT T_ZBEDS ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line>).
    CALL FUNCTION 'FI_F4_ZTERM'
        EXPORTING
            I_KOART = 'K'
            I_ZTERM = <line>-zterm
            I_XSHOW = ''
            I_ZTYPE = ''
            I_NO_POPUP = 'X'
        IMPORTING
            E_ZTERM = v_text
        EXCEPTIONS
            NOTHING_FOUND = 1
            OTHERS = 2.

    WRITE v_text TO <line>-Z_TEXTLONG.
```

From what I gathered, this does not work due to `FI_F4_ZTERM` writing the *list* it returns into `E_ZTERM`, not a single value, which would be what I need. I am a bit lost as to what I should do next. I tried looking into how exactly `FI_F4_ZTERM` generates these texts or where it calls them from, but I was not successful. Currently, I am trying to maybe get this text from `V_T052`, but that does not work either. I would be thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: What is `Z_TEXTLONG` please? Where is it located? If it's a custom "thing", how come it is displayed and returned by `FI_F4_ZTERM`, which is standard? `E_ZTERM` does return a single value, so what do you mean? Thank you. NB: term texts are located in table `T052U`.

Answer (score 0):

Try function FI_TEXT_ZTERM, it has single import parameter I_T052

Answer (score 0):

why not just call   `CALL FUNCTION 'FI_F4_ZTERM'`
with I_NO_POPUP = 'X'
importing
ET_ZTERM  = lt_zterm.

you get the list of payment terms and their texts.
Then in the loop read it from the table of payment terms.

```
 LOOP AT T_ZBEDS ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line>).
    read table lt_zterm assigning <term> 
             with key ZTERM = <line>-zterm.
 ENDLOOP.
```